# Include subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ftp, subdirectory

I have a sub folder with php files.

Like this: domain.com/subfolder/file.php

It would be very useful to call the php files as if they were on the root folder, without ignoring the existing root files.

Is there a way to include a subfolder and all its contents through .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule in root/.htaccess :

```
 RewriteEngine on


 #1--If the request is not for an existent root directory--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #2--And the request is not for an existent root file--#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#3--Then, rewrite the request to "/subfolder"--#
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /subfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

The RewriteConditions above are important to avoid rewriting your root folder and files to /subfolder.

Or try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#--if /document_root/subfolder/foo is an existent dir--#
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/$1 -d [OR]
#--OR /document_root/subfolder/foo is an existent file--#
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/$1 -f
#--rewrite "/foo" to "/subfolder/foo--#
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /subfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: The second option works! How about adding more folders? Copying and pasting the same rewrites will do or it can bottleneck the server?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ $1
```

It should help I think

P.S please make sure that apache rewrite module is enabled and turned of in .htaccess file